# SSH multi-hop with certificate

Tags: ssh, certificates

I need make a SSH multi hop connection from A --> B --> C.

B is a bastion host and C is the target. In my client (A), I have two SSH certificates, one for B and one for C.

How do I connect to C without having the certificate for C on the host B?

Comment: ssh local forwarding should to this job.

Comment: What do you mean by certificate C in host B? Have you tried tunneling? http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: I need have the 2 certiifcate (for B and C) only in A

Comment: What is the certificate? the public key to connect without a password? the string that identifies a server so that no MIM atack can take place and is kept in the known_hosts file?

Comment: The certificates are private keys without password, into B and C the public keys are stored to `authorized_hosts`

Comment: What is the purpose of this? is it possible for you to keep a connection running from B to C and then acces C from A through B? If that is the case the link I posted will show you how to do it, connection from B to C may be stablished with user/password and you don't need to have the private key there.

Comment: Host C is public and must have a SSH key , we are a team that works from different parts of the world , and from different IP. I would use a bastion host and not to copy SSH keys in the bastion host but must remain in the PC of user

Comment: Check this out http://serverfault.com/questions/561572/ssh-forwardagent-multiple-hops

Comment: @YoMismo got the solution!